# Map gclid with campaign name

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I am running ad campaigns and I want to track the performance of users I acquire through those ads.

With the user data I get the gclid , I want to map this gclid with the campaign name or campaign id.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using tranfser of Google Ads data in BigQuery if you use GCP. You should be able to see table with gclid values and campaign id